# Update CSS variable in Angular

Tags: css, angular

I want to use in my Angular app Bennett Feely ["Image-effects"](https://bennettfeely.com/image-effects/).

For exemple this is the 'photo-border-effect':

```css
.photo-border-effect {
  background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/56/Point_Reyes_Lighthouse_%28April_2012%29.jpg/593px-Point_Reyes_Lighthouse_%28April_2012%29.jpg), url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/56/Point_Reyes_Lighthouse_%28April_2012%29.jpg/593px-Point_Reyes_Lighthouse_%28April_2012%29.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 60%, 20%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
}

[class$=-effect] img {
    vertical-align: top !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    opacity: 0 !important;
}

/* CodePen Styles */
body {
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
}
div {
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="photo-border-effect">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/56/Point_Reyes_Lighthouse_%28April_2012%29.jpg/593px-Point_Reyes_Lighthouse_%28April_2012%29.jpg">
</div>
```

But I have to change the urls in the CSS manually, not very convenient for my app. I know I can use [CSS variables](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_variables.asp) but I can't find a way to update it from my .ts directly.

What is the proper way to update CSS variable in Angular?

Mihir Dave response could work but I have cases with different `background-image` in the same class:

```
.flannel-effect {
  background-image: url(photo.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

@supports (background-blend-mode: overlay) {
  .flannel-effect {
    background-image: url(photo.jpg), url(photo.jpg), url(photo.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 100%, 100000% 100%, 100% 100000%;
    background-blend-mode: overlay;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a quick and easy way to do it.

I use CSS variables and set the value from my .ts using `DomSanitizer`.

Here is a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/image-effectsdynamic-pics) with this solution implemented.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the background image from the CSS and pass it from a template using angular like this.

```
<div [style.background-image]="'url('+YourUrlFromVariable+')'"></div>
```

you can also create a method in the ts file with your business logic to return a string

```
<div [style.background-image]="getBackGroudImage()"></div>
```

TS

```
getHeroes(): string {
    // add cases here based on which you can return different strings to background urls
    return 'url('+YourUrlFromVariable+'), url(photo.jpg);';
}
```

Comment: But some effects needs `background-image: url(photo.jpg), url(photo.jpg);`

Comment: @TotoBriac please check the Updated answer.

Comment: Could work but I am facing an other issue, plese check updated question